# How to set a datagridview cell value color on basis of if condition

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with many columns and many rows of data and i want to set some cells color to red or green,so that i have used below code
And as my code illustrates the column "exam" is not reading and not entering into the if condition.please suggest me what to do for my issue.

```
dataGridView2_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)//I have used this event

string unit = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Columns["exam"]);//One of my datagridview 
//column name is exam and in that column cells will be unit1 or unit2 or unit3 or unit 4 or quarterly or halfyearly or yearly
             if (unit == "Unit1"  || unit == "Unit2" || unit == "Unit3" || unit == "Unit4")
              {
                  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                  {

                      for (int j = 7; j < dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                      {
                          if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) < 13)
                          {
                              dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                          }


                          else 
                          { 
                              dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                          }
                      }
                  }

              }
              else
              {
                  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                  {

                      for (int j = 7; j < dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                      {

                          if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) < 35 )
                             dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                         else
                              dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                      }
                  }
              }
```

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-change-GridView-Row-Background-Color-based-on-condition-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code what i wanted exactly..
I hope it will help others..

```
 private void dataGridView3_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string unit = Convert.ToString(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
            if (unit == "Unit1" || unit == "Unit2" || unit == "Unit3" || unit == "Unit4")
            {
                for (int k = 7; k < dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    int val = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value);
                    if (val <= 12)
                    {
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[k].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[k].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    }

                }
            }

            else
            {
                for (int j = 7; j < dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) < 35)
                    {
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using == notation use `.Equals()` to check whether they are equal or not.

```
if (unit.Equals("Unit 1") ||unit.Equals("Unit1") || unit.Equals("Unit2") || unit.Equals("Unit3") || unit.Equals("Unit4"))
    {
        //your logic
    }
```

apply the above logic and also use

```
string data = (string)MyDataGridView[Colnum, Rownum].Value;
```

Then you can simply loop rows and columns

Cheers! Hope it helps.

Comment: “==” compares if the object references are same while “.Equals()” compares if the contents are same.

Comment: My code is only reading else part not if part..please read my problem once

Comment: oh! my bad. I will modify the answer

Comment: there are many rows..not a single row to compare.. so for that what should i do..
the column "exam" will have many values Unit1 or Unit2 so on

Comment: by keeping the column number as constant, loop through the row number using an iterator.